# WPF: Multibinding with string literal and property in a trigger

Tags: wpf, xaml, multibinding

I'm trying to set a `TextBlock.Text` in a trigger. Everything works fine if I bind property in the setter, but how do I "concat" a string and a property?
For instance, I've got a `Date` property. I want the text to be "The date is 9/21/2017."
So far, I managed to show "9/21/2017", but can't figure out how to concat a string before it (I present you only the "interesting part"):

```xml
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding State}" Value="{x:Static model:Croissant+CroissantState.IsUsed}">
    <Setter Property="Text">
        <Setter.Value>
            <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0:d}">
                <Binding Path="Date" />
            </MultiBinding>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</DataTrigger>
```

Any advice on how to bind a string literal? Do I have to use a converter for this or is there an "easy way"?

Comment: try Text="{Binding MyProperty, StringFormat=The date is: {0:d}}"

Comment: Almost! In my case it works with `<Binding Path="Date" StringFormat="The date is {0:d}" />`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who doesn't read the comment, and thanks to Ayyappan Subramanian, the solution is:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding State}" Value="{x:Static model:Croissant+CroissantState.IsUsed}">
    <Setter Property="Text">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Binding Path="Date" StringFormat="The date is {0:d}" />
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</DataTrigger>
```